# Error while Connecting griddb hosted on WSL via jdbc

Tags: jdbc, windows-subsystem-for-linux, griddb

I have installed griddb on WSL as per documentation. I am able to connect via java-client on WSL. Now, I am trying to connect griddb using jdbc(from windows environment to WSL hosted griddb). Below is code:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;

import com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.Collection;
import com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.GSException;
import com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.GridStore;
import com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.GridStoreFactory;
import com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.Query;
import com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.RowKey;
import com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.RowSet;

public class GridStoreConnectionExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws GSException {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("notificationAddress", "192.168.139.234");
        props.setProperty("notificationPort", "20001");
        props.setProperty("clusterName", "defaultCluster");
        props.setProperty("user", "admin");
        props.setProperty("password", "admin");
        GridStore store = GridStoreFactory.getInstance()
            .getGridStore(props);

        // working till here
        Collection<String, Person> people = store.putCollection("PEOPLE", Person.class);
        
        Person person = people.createRow();


        Query<Person> query = people.query("select * where name = 'John'");
        RowSet<Person> rs = query.fetch(false);
        while (rs.hasNext()) {
            // Update the searched Row
            Person person1 = rs.next();
                System.out.println("Name: "+ person1.name +" Age: "+ person1.age);
        }
        System.out.println("endded connection");
    }

    static class Person {

        @RowKey
        String name;
        int age;
    }

    static class HeartRate {

        @RowKey
        Date ts;
        int heartRate;
        String activity;
    }

}
```

Using "192.168.139.234" as address as it is host address for wsl. Also I have used below command as per WSL [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/networking#accessing-linux-networking-apps-from-windows-localhost) to enable port access outside WSL.

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=20001 listenaddress=127.0.0.1 connectport=20001 connectaddress=192.168.139.234
```

I am getting exception, bad connection reason[Not a multicast address]:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/D:/griddb_jarfiles/jar_files/slf4j-jdk14-1.7.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/Omkar/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-jdk14/1.7.7/slf4j-jdk14-1.7.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerFactory]
Feb 02, 2024 2:04:44 AM com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.GridStoreLogger$Connection info
INFO: Retry started (context=5f282abb, statement=null, orgAddress=null, partition=0, statementId=0, trialCount=0)
com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.common.GSConnectionException: [145028:JC_BAD_CONNECTION] Failed to update by notification (address=/192.168.139.234:20001, reason=Not a multicast address)
    at com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.subnet.NodeResolver.updateMasterInfo(NodeResolver.java:854)
    at com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.subnet.NodeResolver.prepareConnectionAndClusterInfo(NodeResolver.java:558)
    at com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.subnet.NodeResolver.getPartitionCount(NodeResolver.java:241)
    at com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.subnet.GridStoreChannel$5.execute(GridStoreChannel.java:2277)
    at com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.subnet.GridStoreChannel.executeStatement(GridStoreChannel.java:1847)
    at com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.subnet.GridStoreChannel.executeResolver(GridStoreChannel.java:2084)
    at com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.subnet.GridStoreChannel.resolvePartitionId(GridStoreChannel.java:2274)
    at com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.subnet.SubnetGridStore.putContainer(SubnetGridStore.java:992)
    at com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.subnet.SubnetGridStore.putCollection(SubnetGridStore.java:1049)
    at com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.subnet.SubnetGridStore.putCollection(SubnetGridStore.java:797)
    at com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.subnet.SubnetGridStore.putCollection(SubnetGridStore.java:100)
    at com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.partitioned.PartStore.putCollection(PartStore.java:177)
    at gridfs.GridStoreConnectionExample.main(GridStoreConnectionExample.java:30)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Not a multicast address
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.DatagramSocketAdaptor.checkGroup(DatagramSocketAdaptor.java:515)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.DatagramSocketAdaptor.joinGroup(DatagramSocketAdaptor.java:521)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.DatagramSocketAdaptor.joinGroup(DatagramSocketAdaptor.java:481)
    at java.base/java.net.MulticastSocket.joinGroup(MulticastSocket.java:325)
    at com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.subnet.NodeResolver.updateMasterInfo(NodeResolver.java:780)
    ... 12 more
```

I have tried connecting using jdbc uri method also, part of the code as below:

```
    String jdbcAddress = "192.168.139.234";
    String jdbcPort = "20001";
    String clusterName = "defaultCluster";
    String databaseName = "public";
    String username = "admin";
    String password = "admin";
    String applicationName = "SampleJDBC";

    // Encoding a cluster name and a database name
    String encodeClusterName = URLEncoder.encode(clusterName, "UTF-8");
    String encodeDatabaseName = URLEncoder.encode(databaseName, "UTF-8");

    // Creating a URL (Multicast method)
    String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:gs://" + jdbcAddress + ":" + jdbcPort + "/" + encodeClusterName + "/" + encodeDatabaseName;

    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.setProperty("user", username);
    prop.setProperty("password", password);
    prop.setProperty("applicationName", applicationName);
    System.out.println("Intiating");

    Class.forName("com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.sql.Driver");
    // Connecting
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, prop);

    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    ...
```

It gets stuck at `Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, prop);`. I am able to access http server hosted on same WSL, 8080 port.